# Difference between two dates gives the difference in days but I would like to have it in years

Tags: python, python-polars

I am collecting the date of birth of users in a polars dataframe and based on today's date, I would like to calculate the age of the users.
This returns their age but in days. Is there a way to add a feature to easily convert days into years? Code preview below:

```
def calculate_age(df):
    
    # I can only get the days and cannot convert into years 
    
    today_date = date.today()
    df = df.with_columns(today = today_date)\
           .with_columns(age =  ((pl.col('today') - pl.col('dob'))))
    return df
```

Result

```
print(df.select('age'))
shape: (10, 1)
┌──────────────┐
│ age │
│ --- │
│ duration[μs] │
╞══════════════╡
│ 27664d │
│ 20104d │
│ 15611d │
│ 19650d │
│ … │
│ 20542d │
│ 15490d │
│ 14811d │
│ 13898d │
└──────────────┘
```

Comment: Divide by 365...?

Comment: dividing gives these weird results 1.7068e15 │
│ 1.7050e15 │
│ 1.7040e15 │
│ 1.7049e15 │
│ …         │
│ 1.7051e15 │
│ 1.7039e15 │
│ 1.7038e15 │
│ 1.7036e15 │

Comment: this is scientific notation `1.7068e15` is the same as `1.7068 * 10^15`. Please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a small sample of the database.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
   'dob': [date(1960, 1, 1), date(1960, 8, 1), date(2001, 1, 2)]
})
```

You can do

```py
today = date.today()
df.with_columns(
    age=pl.when(
        pl.date(pl.col("dob").dt.year(), today.month, today.day) >= pl.col("dob")
    )
    .then(today.year - pl.col("dob").dt.year())
    .otherwise(today.year - pl.col("dob").dt.year() - 1)
)
```

and get

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬─────┐
│ dob        ┆ age │
│ ---        ┆ --- │
│ date       ┆ i32 │
╞════════════╪═════╡
│ 1960-01-01 ┆ 64  │
│ 1960-08-01 ┆ 63  │
│ 2001-01-02 ┆ 23  │
└────────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: how would you be able to get `age` column from nowhere?

Comment: I created the `'age'` column, starting from the `'dob'` column

Comment: You can tweak that a bit so as to not need the when/then...`today.year - pl.col("dob").dt.year() - (pl.date(pl.col("dob").dt.year(), today.month, today.day) < pl.col("dob"))`

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just divide 365.25, 0.25 is for leap year for 1/4

```
df = df.with_columns(today=today_date)\
           .with_columns(age=((pl.col('today') - pl.col('dob')).dt.days) / 365.25)
    return df
```

add format to fix it to two decimal or

```
df['age'] = df['age'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:.2f}')  # Format age with two decimal places
```

you can close scientific notation

```
import numpy as np

# Set the printing options to suppress scientific notation
np.set_printoptions(precision=15, suppress=True)
```

Comment: I have tried this. This would be the result when dividing by 365.25:

│ 1.7068e15 │
│ 1.7050e15 │
│ 1.7040e15 │

Comment: you have scientific notation format in your consule, I edited answer

Comment: But `1.7068e15` is not the right value for a person's age, whether you write it in scientific notation or not.

Comment: Anyway, this code throws: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'method' and 'float'`